# ASP.NET UserControl's OnUnload() method executing multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, page-lifecycle

Our Usercontrol has OnUnload Method, which executes multipe times for the first time, and when I close the page and click again same OnUnload () method executes only once.

OnUnload() method executing multiple times causing the issue.

To replicate this issue if we already opened once. Either we have to close the browser or we have to clear the cookies and cache.

```
protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnUnload(e);
    Controller.ReprojectionsRequestDetail = this.RequestReprojectionDetail;
}
```

when OnUnload() runs for the second time(for the first time when page is loaded) this.RequestReprojectionDetail is null and causing problem.

Only Additional info I can provide is recently our code has been migrated to .net framework 4.5 .

Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Base class is System.Web.UI.Control and has below definition for ONUnload method: [code] // // Summary: // Raises the System.Web.UI.Control.Unload event. // // Parameters: // e: // An System.EventArgs object that contains event data. protected internal virtual void OnUnload(EventArgs e); [code] This method is different from Unload.

Comment: If the root-cuase is not known why not add some code to prevent the null value being set on the Controller?

Comment: Adding logic to check NUll will resolve the issue, but the produciton fix does look appropriate. Looking for root cause, if any one can help or might faced such issues in past.